# MySQL - querying a database for date ranges

Tags: php, mysql

I have an inventory system for adding items that can be hired out. I am trying to run a MySQL query to see if an item is already out for hire, before adding the new hire to the system. I am having to join 2 tables to do this; hire and hire_items.

hire contains the following fields: `hire_id, account_id, hire_start_date, hire_end_date, hire_return_date, total_hire_cost, notes and booking date`.

hire_items contains the following fields: `hire_item_id, hire_id, item_id and item_hire_cost`.

I have already tried the following query, which doesn't error, but does allow me to add a hire where items are already hired out:

```
SELECT i.item_id
FROM hire_items AS i
INNER JOIN hire AS h ON i.hire_id = h.hire_id
WHERE ((item_id = $selected_item_id) AND ($hsd >= h.hire_start_date AND $hsd <= h.hire_return_date)) OR ((item_id = $selected_item_id) AND ($hed >= h.hire_start_date AND $hed <= h.hire_return_date)) OR ((item_id = $selected_item_id) AND ($hrd >= h.hire_start_date AND $hrd <= h.hire_return_date))
```

`$hsd` is the hire start date (from an input)
`$hed` is the hire end date (from an input)
`$hrd` is the hire return date (from an input)

Comment: if you're using native date/datetime fields, then `between` works as expected `... where datefield BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD'`, where the lowercase version must be lower/earlier than the uppercase version.

Comment: I've tried changing my query as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. One thing I've also thought about, is where hire is for 1 day, in which case the start and end dates will be the same and the inputted date will not be between a date range. Is there any reason my original query would not work as expected?

Comment: `A between B and C` is the exact same thing as `(B <= A) && (A <= C)`. it's inclusive.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, never had to use it before. This is what I now have and still no luck: `SELECT i.item_id FROM hire_items AS i INNER JOIN hire AS h ON i.hire_id = h.hire_id WHERE ((item_id = $selected_item_id) AND ($hsd BETWEEN h.hire_start_date AND h.hire_return_date)) OR ((item_id = $selected_item_id) AND ($hed BETWEEN h.hire_start_date AND h.hire_return_date)) OR ((item_id = $selected_item_id) AND ($hrd BETWEEN h.hire_start_date AND h.hire_return_date))`

Comment: you didn't quote the date values, e.g. `$hsd`, so your `yyyy-mm-dd` values are being seen as mathematical subtraction, e.g. `2015-12-10 BETWEEN a AND B` is actually `1993 BETWEEN a AND b`. In other words, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB that has worked perfectly. Your help and patience is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.item_id
FROM hire_items AS i
INNER JOIN hire AS h ON i.hire_id = h.hire_id
WHERE (item_id = $selected_item_id)
AND ($hsd NOT BETWEEN h.hire_start_date AND h.hire_return_date) 
AND ($hrd NOT BETWEEN h.hire_start_date AND h.hire_return_date) 
AND (h.hire_start_date NOT BETWEEN CAST($hsd AS DATE) AND CAST($hrd AS DATE))
```

This queries for

1. The correct item by ID, but only once
2. That the inputted start date is not during a time of hire
3. That the inputted return date is not during a time of hire
4. That the inputted start/return time does not enclose a time of hire